# Notification Timeout Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a button that fetches an image based on certain parameters and on success or failure it outputs a span with a flash message.

```
      $.getJSON('<%= EVERCAM_API %>cameras/test.json?' + params.join('&'))
      .done(function (resp) {
        console.log('success');
        $('#test-error').text('Snapshot successfully retrieved');
        $('#testimg-add').attr('src', resp.data);
      })
      .fail(function (resp) {
        $('#test-error').text(resp.responseJSON.message);
        console.log('error');
      })
      .always(function () {
        l.stop();
        clearInterval(interval);
      });
});
```

What I want is for the #text-error that displays on the page when the button is pressed

```
 <span id="test-error"><%= flash[:message] %></span>
```

to fade in and fade out along these lines

```
that.show = function(text) {
  clearTimeout(hideHandler);

  elem.find("span").html(text);
  elem.delay(200).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();
};
```

The above fadeIn fadeOut snippet of code I got from elsewhere and I'm not quite sure how to write that into my existing function to get the #test-error fading in and out. At the moment it just outputs on the age and stays.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I would go about this?

Comment: Where do `l` and `interval` come from?

Comment: They are just there to start and stop a ladda wheel that shows on the button while it is attempting to fetch the image.